# Upload app to Apple Connect failed after change my mac's user name and home folder name

Tags: ios

### I renamed my user name and home folder name from old_name to new_name on my Mac.Then i'm trying to upload my app to app connect using XCode and Transporter, but i got two error messages:

Resolver: Install error - org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore Exception's name: java.io.IOException, Exception's message: Error accessing file:/Users/old_name/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/obr/2.0.0/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore-4.4.11.jar

Could not find the service with interface (com.apple.transporter.osgi.TransporterService)

---

And there are com.apple.amp.itmstransporter in my /Users/b/Library/Caches/.

Anyone can help?